# Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding' PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Hi I am using this script to upload a file to a library on share point but i am getting this error any help is appreciated.

```
 $Output = "c:\temp\users_PermisionReport.txt" 
 $WebURL = "http://url" 
 $ListName = "Documents"

 //Create something to upload, in this case a list of all sites

Get-SPSite | Out-File -FilePath "url" $Output

//Upload the results to SharePoint 

$File = Get-Item $Output 
$Stream = $File.OpenRead() 
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL 
$List = $Web.Lists["$ListName"] 
$FileCollection = $List.RootFolder.Files 
$FileCollection.Add($File.Name,$Stream,$true) 
$Stream.Close() 
$File.Delete()
```

## this is the error:

```
Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument 
"c:\temp\users_PermisionReport.txt" does not
 belong to the set 
"unknown,string,unicode,bigendianunicode,utf8,utf7,utf32,ascii,default,oem" 
specified by the
ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try 
the command again.
At C:\Users\balaji.chode\Desktop\UpDoc.ps1:6 char:59
+ Get-SPSite | Out-File -FilePath "url" $Output
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], 
ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :
```

ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand

I am using share point server admin shell. thank you

Comment: Did you write the code in the post by hand or did you copy-paste from the actual script? Most likely there's some invisible or extended unicode character that PowerShell doesn't treat as whitespace and therefore thinks is intended as a parameter argument

Comment: The `-Encoding` parameter is recognized at position 1. Hence, `Get-SPSite | Out-File -FilePath "url" $Output` is the same as (supposedly wrong) `Get-SPSite | Out-File -FilePath "url" -Encoding $Output`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Set the variables
$WebURL = “http://sharepoint:20000/ubt/it/”
$DocLibName = “Documents”
$FilePath = “c:\temp\users_PermisionReport2.txt”

//Get a variable that points to the folder
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName)
$Files = $List.Files

//Get just the name of the file from the whole path
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1)

//Load the file into a variable
$File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

//Upload it to SharePoint
$Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false)
$web.Dispose()
```

I used this script it is working now. However,the other one still don't why it is not working but this one does the same job.